# Chart.JS drawing graph points over axis, but not graph lines

Tags: javascript, html, charts

Im looking for a way to draw the graph points over the axis, but not the lines in Chart.js

I tried changing the order, the z. I tried having two data sets one with only the dots the other with only the lines also didnt work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.